# For looping through array doesn't return correct result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm comparing a variable with an array: `$scope.object.id` and `$scope.groepen.id` with an if statement after using a for loop. If `$scope.object.id` is exactly the same as one of the IDs of `$scope.groepen.id`, then it should make that index of `$scope.overlap` true.

I'm using another if check to see if anything of `$scope.overlap` is true. If one element of `$scope.overlap` is true, it will make `$scope.bestaand` true. Else it should make it false.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.groepen.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.object.id === $scope.groepen[i].id) {
    $scope.overlap[i] = true;
    if ($scope.overlap[i]) {
      $scope.bestaand = true;
    }
    else {
      $scope.bestaand = false;
    }
  }
  else {
    $scope.overlap[i] = false;
  }
}
```

My console log shows me that `$scope.overlap` does in fact show the correct values (so if nothing is the same, all indexes are false). `$scope.bestaand` does turn to true if something is the same, but it doesn't change back to false.

I'm using Angular form validation to show if the check is working or not shown here:

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : bestaand }">
    <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Groepsnaam</label> 
    <input id="groepen" name="groepen" type="text" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="object.id" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="16" ng-change="checkOverlap()" required>
    <p ng-show="bestaand" class="help-block">Deze groepsnaam bestaat al!</p>                            
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

I have changed the place of my if statements. Updated code shown here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.groepen.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.object.id === $scope.groepen[i].id) {
    $scope.overlap[i] = true;
  }
  else {
    $scope.overlap[i] = false;

  }
  if ($scope.overlap[i]) {
      $scope.bestaand = true;
      console.log("works")
  }
  else {
    $scope.bestaand = false;
    console.log("doesnt work")
  }
}
```

The console log shows me this:

[image]

It seems that it does become true, but it gets overwritten (I have input a value that is the same as the second value of the array). If I input a value that is the same as the LAST value of the array, it does work.

Comment: The reason why is because `$scope.bestaand` should probably be an array at the index of the loop to match each `$scope.overlap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you've enclosed `if ($scope.overlap[i]) {` inside `if ($scope.object.id === $scope.groepen[i].id) {` so `$scope.overlap` will always be true.  This means `$scope.bestaand` will only ever be set to `true` or left as `undefined`.  What you actually want is -

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.groepen.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.object.id === $scope.groepen[i].id) {
    $scope.overlap[i] = true;
  }
  else {
    $scope.overlap[i] = false;
  }
  if ($scope.overlap[i]) {
    $scope.bestaand = true;
  }
  else {
    $scope.bestaand = false;
  }
}
```

**Edit**
If you want  to set `$scope.bestaand` to true if any of your `$scope.overlap` elements is true then you will want something a little different -

```
$scope.bestaand = false;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.groepen.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.object.id === $scope.groepen[i].id) {
    $scope.overlap[i] = true;
  }
  else {
    $scope.overlap[i] = false;
  }
  if(!$scope.bestaand) {
    if ($scope.overlap[i]) {
      $scope.bestaand = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have put the if check outside of the `if ($scope.object.id === $scope.groepen[i].id)`. This gives me a different result. `$scope.bestaand` only becomes true if the last value of `$scope.groepen.id` is the same as `$scope.object.id`.

Comment: I have applied your code with a bit of console logging. When `$scope.bestaand` = true, I log "it works". Else I log "it doesn't work". In my console I see "it doesn't work" first, then it logs "it works", then 9 times "it doesn't work" (probably due to the other objects in the array).

Comment: @Johnson - If I'm understanding you correctly you want to use `$scope.bestaand` to be false if any `$scope.overlap` element is true?

Comment: `$scope.bestaand` stays true after applying your code. Sorry for the trouble. This issue is mind boggling. Have you looked at my edit? It might give a bit more information about the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98210/discussion-between-john-c-and-johnson).

Answer (score 1):

This is because **else** statement is unreachable:

```
$scope.overlap[i] = true;

if ($scope.overlap[i]) {
  $scope.bestaand = true;
}
else {
  console.log('UNREACHABLE');
  $scope.bestaand = false;
}
```

As for your edited question:

Your `$scope.bestaand` indicate an error, so I assume that if it be false once it should never be true.

So you need to rewrite your loop as follows:

```
$scope.bestaand = false;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.groepen.length; i++) {
  if ($scope.object.id === $scope.groepen[i].id) {
    $scope.overlap[i] = true;
  } else {
    $scope.overlap[i] = false;
  }

  if ($scope.overlap[i] && !$scope.bestaand) {
    $scope.bestaand = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: My else does get reached after testing. I have console logged both `$scope.overlap` and `$scope.bestaand`. It shows me all values of `$scope.overlap` false if the inputted value is not the same as one of the IDs, yet if the inputted value is the same, `$scope.bestaand` does not become true.

Comment: It should become true after becoming false. I compare values. If the values are the same, it should be true. If values or not the same, it should become false. This is how I will use the Angular form validation (unless there's a different way?). I have applied your code and it's also not giving me the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

because there is no case you set it to false.
`if ($scope.object.id === $scope.groepen[i].id)` is true, then you already set it `overlap = true`, if overlap is false, you don't set `bastaan = false` in any case